# CKEditor 5 links: Set default target for links or edit target

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

In CKEditor 5 I don't see field for target attribute in link dialog.

[image]

How to add such field? Or set target=_blank as default.
Thanks

Comment: It's absolutely bizarre that there's no easy way to do this. What on earth were the developers thinking???

Answer (score 3):

Since version `11.1.0` of a [Link Plugin](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-link), there is added [link decorator](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/link.html#custom-link-attributes-decorators) feature. This feature provides an easy way to define rules when and how to add some extra attributes to links.

There might be manual or automatic [decorators](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_link_link-LinkConfig.html#member-decorators).

First provides a UI switch which might be toggled by the user. When the user edits a link and toggles it, then preconfigured attributes will be added to the link e.g. `target="_blank"`.

Second one, are applied automatically when content is obtained from the Editor. Here you need to provide a callback function which based on link's URL decides if a given set of attributes should be applied.

There is also a preconfigured decorator, which might be turn on with simple [`config.link.addTargetToExternalLinks=true`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_link_link-LinkConfig.html#member-addTargetToExternalLinks). It will add `target="blank"` and `rel="noopener noreferrer"` to all links started with: `http://`, `https://` or `//`.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by adding this code in CKEditor Initialization Script:

```
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
        // ...
        link: {
            decorators: {
                openInNewTab: {
                    mode: 'manual',
                    label: 'Open in a new tab',
                    defaultValue: true,         // This option will be selected by default.
                    attributes: {
                        target: '_blank',
                        rel: 'noopener noreferrer'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } )
    .then( ... )
    .catch( ... );
```

Here is the [Documentation Link](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/link.html) . It will be working fine.

Comment: `addTargetToExternalLinks: true` did not work for me, but this solution did.